# Typescript + eslint Linter not get errors

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I follow de [docs](https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/linting/#installation) to setup typescript with eslint.

Then e put in my package.json this script entry `"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts --quiet src/"` when i run `npm run lint` i got

```
> eslint --ext .js,.ts --quiet src/


Process finished with exit code 0
```

But i have a file i know is wrong, and when i open it i could see the errors

[image]

```
TS2322: Type '{ id: string; created_at: Date; due_date: Date; reminder_at: Date;
expiration_date: Date; paid_at: Date | null; paid_amount: number; status: string;
paid_interest_and_fine?: number | undefined; ... 16 more ...; taxes: Taxes; }' is not 
assignable to type 'SubscriptionPaymentItem'.   Types of property 
'paid_interest_and_fine' are incompatible.     Type 'number | undefined' is not 
assignable to type 'number'.       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Using webstorm if it matter somehow.

So my question is: eslint was not supposed to point this errors??

Here is the important part of my eslintrc, the `extends` has more than the tutorial cause it comes from an firebase functions project

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: ['tsconfig.json', 'tsconfig.dev.json'],
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    '/lib/**/*', // Ignore built files.
    '/database/**/*',
    '**/experiments/**/*',
  ],
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'google',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'plugin:import/errors',
    'plugin:import/warnings',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
  ],
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'import', 'simple-import-sort'],
```

Comment: That's a TypeScript compiler error, and has nothing to do with ESLint. ESLint is used to catch different types of problems.

Comment: mmmm so misunderstand it a lot. The only way to get the error in the pic is "building" with `tsc` ?

Comment: Yes correct. `tsc` will check the types for you in the command line. If you don't want any output files, you can also run it as `tsc --noEmit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as pointed by @Phil, what i really need was to use tsc with `--noEmit` flag